# How to apply an 'indicator' function to infinite product?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, piecewise-continuity

Suppose there exists an 'indicator' function whose argument is the positive integers $n$, and which yields $1$ or $0$ depending on whether $n$ is a member of some set $S$:

$$f(n):=
\begin{cases}
1,  & n\in S \\
0, & n\notin S
\end{cases}$$

I want to find the infinite product

$$\prod_{n\in S}n$$

but I want to express it in terms of all $n$ rather than pre-selecting $n\in S$, so that for some function $g$

$$\prod_{n\in S}n=\prod_{n=1}^\infty g(n)$$

Is it possible to find $g$ as a function of $f$?

If the series was a summation rather than a product it would of course be easy:

$$\sum_{n\in S}n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) n$$

But the product case appears to be much harder, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes $$\prod _{n \in \mathbb N}n^{f(n)}$$

Comment: I feel so stupid! Thank you.